# How to hit the url in phone gap and parse the result using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova

am having one task in phonegap,that is registration page if the use  click the registration page means the values are going to hit the url and if the  users is alreay avaiable or not means  it returns the data as json.the following code i used:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var username = $('#uid').val();
        var email=$('#email').val();
        var password=$('#pass').val();
        var firstname = $('#first').val();
        var lastname=$('#last').val();
        var dob=$('#dob').val();

        var param = 'username=' + username + '&email=' + email +'&password='+password+'&firstname='+firstname+'&lastname='+lastname+'&dob='+dob;
        alert("hi");
        alert(param);
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://demourl/api/reg.php?",
            type: 'GET',
            data: param,
            success: function(result) {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function(result) {
                alert("jQuery Error:" + result.statusText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

response from the reg.php is like this: `[{"error":"Email is taken"}]`

here i dont know how to parse the data?please help me

Comment: use `$.parseJSON('your result');`

Comment: i used it but i cannt get the value.can you give me a brief code?

Comment: dont use `.ready` with jQuery Mobile, use jQM events http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var username = $('#uid').val();
        var email=$('#email').val();
        var password=$('#pass').val();
        var firstname = $('#first').val();
        var lastname=$('#last').val();
        var dob=$('#dob').val();

        var param = 'username=' + username + '&email=' + email +'&password='+password+'&firstname='+firstname+'&lastname='+lastname+'&dob='+dob;
        alert("hi");
        alert(param);
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://demourl/api/reg?",
            type: 'GET',
            data: param,
            success: function(result) {
                var parseJson = $.parseJSON(result);
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function(result) {
                var parseJson = $.parseJSON(result);
                alert("jQuery Error:" + parseJson.error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: hi,i can see  the response in fire bug.but it did not go to success or error function.

Comment: @Ram: what is your json response? i have updated success function with console log check your console tab in firebug

Comment: :SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Comment: check your json response in http://jsonlint.com/ if it shows valid then it work or else post the json response

Comment: yes i checked but it shows as valid json.and the thing is it goes to error function and not success function.

Comment: Show your json response

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
...
error: function(result) {
  var parsedJSON = $.parseJSON(result);
  alert(parsedJSON.error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding you have asked for

" the return data like this: `[{"error":"Email is taken"}]`

here i dont know how to parse the data? ..."

So accordingly, may may be expecting this one,

```
var data = {"error":"Email is taken"}; 

for(var key in data)
{ 
  console.log('key name: ' + key + ' value: ' + data[key]); 
}
```